# Share a struct between two threads where the struct needs to be bounded by a Trait

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have a struct that implements a trait. The trait is used in a function to keep track of a Vector of objects implementing the trait. These are added via a function. But another thread needs to be able to read from this as well.

I have implemented a system similar to [chapter 16.3](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-03-shared-state.html) in the Rust Book, where the struct is wrapped in Mutex, than Arc. The struct being a device.

```rust
let vga = Arc::new(Mutex::new(device::vga::VGA::new(0xA0000)));
```

Than another struct that will take in that, with other structs.

```rust
let mut map = device::map::DeviceMap::new();
```

I than add the devices.

```rust
map.add(ram);
map.add(rom);
map.add(vga.lock().unwrap().clone());
```

The add function looks like this.

```rust
pub fn add<T: 'static + Device>(&mut self, device: T) {
    self.devices.push(Box::new(device));
}
```

The trait has common function needed between every Device, reading and writing. Map uses these to read and write, and map has these same function but doesn't implement Device.

```rust
pub trait Device {
    fn read(&self, addr: u32) -> DeviceResponse<u16>;
    fn read_byte(&self, addr: u32) -> DeviceResponse<u8>;
    fn write(&mut self, addr: u32, value: u16) -> DeviceResponse<()>;
    fn write_byte(&mut self, addr: u32, value: u8) -> DeviceResponse<()>;
}
```

I clone the device and use it in another thread

```rust
let vga_thread = thread::spawn(move || {
    let vga_scr = Arc::clone(&vga);
    let mut screen = device::vga::Screen::new(vga_scr);
    ...
});
```

The code does compile, but screen doesn't see the changes done in map. I first thought it was the lock not being unlocked. So I put it in it's own scope.

```rust
map.add(rom);
{
    let vga_lock = vga.lock().unwrap();
    map.add(vga_lock.clone());
}
```

But this made no difference. Than I realize, it's because I'm cloning the device. So I remove the clone.

```rust
map.add(rom);
{
    let vga_lock = vga.lock().unwrap();
    map.add(vga_lock);
}
```

But this throws an error and doesn't let me compile:

```rust
error[E0277]: the trait bound `MutexGuard<'_, VGA>: Device` is not satisfied
  --> src/vcpu/mod.rs:42:17
   |
42 |         map.add(vga_lock);
   |             --- ^^^^^^^^ the trait `Device` is not implemented for `MutexGuard<'_, VGA>`
   |             |
   |             required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `Device`:
             Ram
             Rom
             VGA
note: required by a bound in `DeviceMap::add`
  --> src/vcpu/device/map.rs:20:29
   |
20 |     pub fn add<T: 'static + Device>(&mut self, device: T) {
   |                             ^^^^^^ required by this bound in `DeviceMap::add`
```

This makes sense, since MutexGuard is a smart pointer and points to the device. It's built in and doesn't implement the Device trait.

I have also tried mpsc channels but it completely freezes my GUI, which the extra thread is running.

I need to add it to the map without cloning. I have no idea how I would go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you added a device to your `DeviceMap`, you are cloning the object held by the mutex, creating a new copy. This means that changes made to the object held by the mutex will not be made to the object you hold in `DeviceMap`.

For an object to hold a reference to another object shared between threads, it needs to hold an `Arc<Mutex<...>`. Your `DeviceMap` should have something that looks like this:

```rust
pub struct DevieMap {
    devices: Vec<Arc<Mutex<Device>>>,
}
```

You can add a device to your `DeviceMap` with

```rust
let vga = Arc::new(Mutex::new(device::vga::VGA::new(0xA0000)));
map.add(vga.clone());
```

This clones the `Arc`, incrementing the reference count and makes sure the object held by the `Arc` is not dropped until all references are removed.

With the updated signature for `devices`, your add function can look something like this

```rust
pub fn add<T: Device>(&mut self, device: Arc<Mutex<T>>) {
    self.devices.push(device);
}
```

Your `DeviceMap` will then be responsible for locking the mutex when it needs to read or write from the device.

Comment: Was trying to avoid this, as every other device is used in the main thread. But that may be what I need to sacrifice to make this all work. Makes sense that I would need to do that, since I would need to lock it in read anyways. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need an `Arc` if you can work with [scoped threads](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.scope.html) only. But you have to share some sort of reference.